# Add hyperlink to background image only on hover

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm a beginner CSS coder. I am learning javascript (I mostly just use CSS for web animation) but I'm really stuck on this one... I have an image that changes to another image upon hover. I want only the background image to be hyperlinked upon hover. However when I add the link to the page it just doesn't work.

I've looked everywhere for a solution and I can't find one. Thanks for your input here! Here's my code:

```css
#slidingDoors {
  /*Applying the Background Images*/
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/bwtulip-long.jpg'), url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/bwtulip-long.jpg'), url('/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/tulip-stand-out-long.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*Positioning the Background Images*/
  background-position: -239.5px 0px, 239.5px 0px, 0px 0px;
  /*Transition Parameters*/
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#slidingDoors:hover {
  background-position: -479px 0px, 479px 0px, 0px 0px;
}
.circles {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 479px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidingDoors" class="circles">
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="http://www.example.com">
    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x fa-border"></i>
    <br />
    <br />
    <h4 class="parentregistrationtext" style="text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;">Parent Registration / Login</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the link around the div tag.

Comment: Why not make the element a link instead of a div, then style it the same way and use `:hover` to change the background.  There's no point in making something a hyperlink on hover - that's a link. (might have to add `display:block` to the link)

Comment: adding the link around the div tag worked Rachel, thanks! I thought I already tried that but I must have placed the tags incorrectly... ntgCleaner, I tried changing the div to an <a> and it broke the image, not sure why, but i'll just go with the first solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the whole block to be a link?

```css
#slidingDoors {
  /*Applying the Background Images*/
  background-image: url('http://www.ipsroofingproducts.com/IPS/colors/Black.JPG'),
                    url('http://www.ipsroofingproducts.com/IPS/colors/Black.JPG'),
                    url('https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/125723543/q%3D80_h%3D300/a4849982fea993e08837494a890b51da');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*Positioning the Background Images*/
  background-position: -239.5px 0px, 239.5px 0px, 0px 0px;
  /*Transition Parameters*/
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#slidingDoors:hover {
  background-position: -479px 0px, 479px 0px, 0px 0px;
}
.circles {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 479px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="http://www.example.com">
  <div id="slidingDoors" class="circles">
    <br />
    <br />
    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x fa-border"></i>
    <br />
    <br />
    <h4 class="parentregistrationtext" style="text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;">Parent Registration / Login</h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

If so you just need to move the placement of the `<a>` tags

Or do you mean you want the link hidden, so it only appears after you mouse over it?

Comment: I mean, you could add the link on hover, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xx5mvL4k/ .. but what's the purpose, the correct approach is what you did in your snippet. Doing something like adding the link just on hover would not even work in touch screens.